# Derivation of the Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity

I have been reading Young's book called: *University physics with modern physics* and on page 1284 author states that we can derive Lorenz time transformation by eliminating two equations for Lorentz space transformation along the vector of relative speed $u$. First we eliminate them for $x$ and then for $x'$.

The equations to eliminate are:

\begin{equation}
x=\gamma(x'+ut')
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x'=\gamma(x+ut)
\end{equation}

After elimination we are supposed to get the following Lorentz transformations:

\begin{equation}
t'=\gamma(t+ux/c^2)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
t =\gamma(t-ux/c^2)
\end{equation}

There is also an article about this [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0606103v4.pdf). But neither in this article, neither in the Young's book the solution is shown. I have been trying to derive it myself, but failed and am now puting it as a topic on this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the two equations:

$$ x' = \gamma (x - vt) $$

$$ x = \gamma (x' + vt') $$

Note the sign change of $v$ because going from $x'$ to $x$ is in the opposite direction to going from $x$ to $x'$. Rearrange equation 2 to give:

$$ t' = \frac{1}{v} (\frac{x}{\gamma} - x') $$

Now use equation 1 to substitute for $x'$:

$$ t' = \frac{1}{v} (\frac{x}{\gamma} - \gamma (x - vt)) $$

and rearrange to give:

$$ t' = \gamma \left(\frac{x}{v} \frac{1}{\gamma^2} - \frac{x}{v} + t\right) $$

and $1/\gamma^2$ is $1 - v^2/c^2$ so:

$$ t' = \gamma \left(\frac{x}{v} - \frac{xv}{c^2} - \frac{x}{v} + t\right) $$

$$ t' = \gamma \left(t  - \frac{xv}{c^2}\right) $$

And likewise to get the expression for $t$ in terms of $t'$ and $x'$.